# Python requests in AWS Lambda cannot connect to site behind proxy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function that needs to connect to an internal website which is behind a proxy. In my code I am doing the following:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests

https_proxy = "https://myproxy:myport"
proxyDict = { 
          "https" : https_proxy
    }
request.get("https://myurl.json", proxies=proxyDict)
```

Running this gives me the following error message:

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='myproxyhost', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: myurl.json (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', gaierror(-2, 'Name or service not known')))

I have tried replacing the proxied URL with google.com to confirm I can connect to other sites (without the proxy).

It looks like the address space that Lambda runs it gets blocked by the proxy.

Is there something else I need to set with requests and lambda to get this to work?

Comment: You can add https_proxy as a environment variable to your lambda function. it should work for you.

Comment: is your internal website running within VPC. If so, you can configure lambda to run within same VPC, and resolve internal names..

Comment: The proxied website I am trying to connect to is not part of a VPC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: After reading the question again I realised that the error is due to name resolution `(-2, 'Name or service not known')`. If you are using internal Route53 for your VPC, the solution below should still work as the lambda function will use VPC's DNS servers.

It seems either the lambda function is not running on the same subnet of your proxy instance or the security group is blocking the connection. To fix it:

- Create a security group to allow the lambda function to connect to port 443 on your proxy host
- Update your lambda function to use that security group **AND** to be executed inside your subnet:

This script should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Fill the variables bellow with your vpc and subnet id
VPC_ID=""
SUBNET_IDS=""
FUNCTION_NAME=""

SEC_GROUP=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name 'lambda-proxy' --vpc-id $VPC_ID --description 'Lambda/proxy communication' --output text)
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-id ${SEC_GROUP} --protocol tcp --port 443
aws lambda update-function-configuration --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --vpc-config SubnetIds=$SUBNET_IDS,SecurityGroupIds=$SEC_GROUP
```

Then assign the created security group to your instance.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the info... experimenting with it now.

Comment: Giving you the credit for the answer since this is pointing me in the right direction. Was able to get a connection to the proxied URL from a different VPC, leading me to believe the VPC I am running out of has a security group misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of lambda environment variables and can add  https_proxy as a environment variable to lambda function. 
By which your lambda function can access the website via proxy.

Comment: Doesn't this just set a key-value pair that can be recognized in the code? Does it have some other benefit?

Comment: It is equivalent of running export http_proxy <value> , and can be used with or without code. You need not read and set it again explicitly in your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kids of them `security groups`, and `subnets`. You need permit your lambda to access proxy's subnet by providing security group. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html) is step by step tutorial...

Comment: It looks like that tutorial is for when the Lambda function needs to connect to something in an VPC, however the site I need to connect to is not in a VPC, but is but requires a proxy.

When I have an EC2 with the same role attached as the Lambda, the EC2 can reach the Lambda by using a curl command and the link to the site I want to connect to.

Comment: sorry for missing the point - `aws lambda outbound connection`. For instance this tutorial https://medium.com/@philippholly/aws-lambda-enable-outgoing-internet-access-within-vpc-8dd250e11e12